# Removing items from a string before and after certain values

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript string like this:

```
 "INSERT INTO mtable (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?, ?)",
```

I am trying to strip off everything before "(" and after the first ")"

So any generic string formatted like above will return only 
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5

Is there a simple way of accomplishing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this simple set of requirements I think RegExp would be over kill. Plus you would have to compensate for greedy matching. Instead some simple math might be better:

```
function getFirstSet(str) {
  var left = str.indexOf('(');
  var right = str.indexOf(')');
  return '(' + str.substring(left + 1, right) + ')';
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to handle the case when there are no matches.

Comment: `'(' + 'foobar'.substring(-1 + 1, -1) + ')'` will return `()` so that works. If your concerned by mismatched parenthesis then there could be an assertion. That seems it might be out of scope of the question though.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using regular expressions:

```
string.match(/\(([^\)]*)\)/)[1]
```

This means, in the variable called `string`, look for:

- A left bracket
- Followed by a group of characters to be remembered:

  - Any character other than a right bracket
  - Zero or more times
- Followed by a right bracket

And returns the group.